# プログラム実行時にエラー: ZeroDivisionError: disision by zero

Tags: python

以下のプログラムを実行するとエラーとなってしまいます。どこが悪いのでしょうか？

**出力結果:**

[image: 出力結果]

**プログラム:**

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import re
import time
acid=[]
score1=[]
e=[]
path="C:Users/足立 広隆/Desktop/profile/"
wr=open(path+"w.txt","w")
'''
def read_fasta(name):
    f = open(name, 'r')
    seq=''
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line[0] != '>':
            seq += line.strip()
    f.close()
    return seq
'''
###
#X = 'GGGGGUUAAAAAAJJJJJJJJBBBBBBB'#human
#Y = 'TGTGTGGCTGTCACTC'
def alimentt(x_al,x_na):
    time.sleep(1)
    X = x_al
    X_name = x_na
    for acid1 in open(path+"write1.txt","r"):
        aci=re.sub("\n","",acid1)
        ac=aci.split("\t")
        if X_name==str(ac[0]):
            acid.append(ac[2])
    print(acid)
    for YY in open(path+"ns8_keggID_sample_protein_ID.txt","r"):
        YY1=re.sub("\n","",YY)
        YY2=YY1.split("\t")
        Y_moto=YY2[0]
        #print(Y_moto)
        Y_name=YY2[1]
        Y = YY2[2]
        if Y_moto==X_name:
            print(Y_name)
            N = len(X)
            M = len(Y)

            gap_penalty = -2

            H = np.empty((N+1,M+1), dtype='int16')
            L = np.zeros((N+1,M+1), dtype='int8')

            H[0,0]=0
            for j in range(1,M+1):
                H[0,j] = H[0,j-1] + gap_penalty
                L[0,j] = 0

            for i in range(1,N+1):
                H[i,0] = H[i-1,0] + gap_penalty
                L[i,0] = 2

# Horizontal:0 Diagonal:1 Vertical:2
            s = np.array([0,0,0],dtype='int')

            for i in range(1,N+1):
                for j in range (1,M+1):
                    s[0] = H[i,j-1] + gap_penalty

                    if X[i-1]==Y[j-1]:
                        score = +1
                    else:
                        score = -1
                    s[1] = H[i-1,j-1] + score

                    s[2] = H[i-1,j] + gap_penalty

                    H[i,j]=np.max(s)
                    L[i,j]=np.argmax(s)
            pairs=[ ]
            i=N
            j=M
            while i!=0 or j!=0:
                if L[i,j]==0:
                    pairs.append( ["-",Y[j-1]] )
                    j=j-1
                elif L[i,j]==1:
                    pairs.append( [X[i-1],Y[j-1]] )
                    i=i-1
                    j=j-1
                else:
                    pairs.append( [X[i-1],"-"] )
                    i=i-1

            pairs.reverse()
            i=1
            acid_s=0
            acid_all=0
            acid_p=len(acid)
            for p in pairs:
                if p[0]!="-":
                    i=i+1
                    for acid_num in acid:
                        if str(i)==acid_num:
                                #print(p)
                            if p[0]==p[1]:
                                acid_s=acid_s+1
            ac_all=acid_s/acid_p
            ac_al=str(ac_all)
                #print(Y_name,ac_all)
            ac_a=[Y_name,ac_al]
            #print(ac_a)
            score1.append(ac_a)
'''
#print('SCORE=', H[N,M])
for p in pairs:
    print(p[0],end='')
print()

for p in pairs:
    if p[0]==p[1]:
        print('|',end='')
    else:
        print(' ',end='')
print()

for p in pairs:
    print(p[1],end='')
print()
i=0
for p in pairs:
    if p[0]!="-":
        i=i+1
        if i==12:
            print(p)
'''
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wr.write("\t")
    for wwr in open(path+"honyurui.txt"):
        wwr1=re.sub("\n","",wwr)
        wr.write(wwr1+"\t")
        e.append(wwr1)
    wr.write("\n")
    for XX in open(path+"hito_tatejiku.txt","r"):
        score1=[]
        acid=[]
        XX1=re.sub("\n","",XX)
        XX2=XX1.split("\t")
        XX_name=XX2[0]
        XX_aliment=XX2[1]
        print(XX_name)
        alimentt(XX_aliment,XX_name)
        print(score1)
        wr.write(XX_name+"\t")
        for ii in e:
            ii_s=-1
            for jj in score1:
                jj1=jj[0].split(":")
                if ii==jj1[0]:
                    ii_s=jj[1]
            wr.write(str(ii_s)+"\t")
        wr.write("\n")
```

Comment: 0による除算のエラーですから、acid_pの値が0なのだと思います。
acid_pに代入している箇所などを確認してください。

Answer (score 0):

`hito_tatejiku.txt`のタブ区切りデータに記載されている名前に関わるデータが、`write1.txt`の中に無い場合がある、もしくは無い場合の可能性を考慮されていない、と思われます。

行番号は少し違いますが、発生場所から関連部分をたどっていくと以下になります。

```
104:            ac_all=acid_s/acid_p #### エラー発生行(0除算)
    ↓
 95:            acid_p=len(acid)     #### エラー直接原因 acidリストの長さ(要素数)が0
    ↓
 23:def alimentt(x_al,x_na):
 24:    time.sleep(1)
 25:    X = x_al
 26:    X_name = x_na
 27:    for acid1 in open(path+"write1.txt","r"):
 28:        aci=re.sub("\n","",acid1)
 29:        ac=aci.split("\t")       #### タブ区切り"write1.txt"
 30:        if X_name==str(ac[0]):   #### 最初の列が名前で一致すれば
 31:            acid.append(ac[2])   #### 3番目の列のデータをacidリストに追加
    ↓
140:    for XX in open(path+"hito_tatejiku.txt","r"): ####
141:        score1=[]
142:        acid=[]                  #### 初期値は空のリスト
143:        XX1=re.sub("\n","",XX)
144:        XX2=XX1.split("\t")      #### タブ区切り"hito_tatejiku.txt"
145:        XX_name=XX2[0]           #### 最初の列が名前
146:        XX_aliment=XX2[1]
147:        print(XX_name)
148:        alimentt(XX_aliment,XX_name) #### パラメータ指定で呼び出し
```

---

プログラムの目的や内容の詳細は分かりませんが、大まかな流れからすると以下のような対策が考えられます。

- 最初の`for`ループ直後(`print(acid)`の部分)には要素数が分かるので、そこで 0 ならメソッドを終了する。
- 探しても対応するデータが 0 件だったというのも意味があるので、次の`for`ループの中で`score1`にデータを追加出来るところまで処理して、ループの次の回に移行する

**終了するパターンの変更箇所**

```
 32:    print(acid)
 33:    acid_p=len(acid) #### 先に acid_p(acidの要素数)を取得しておく
 34:    if acid_p == 0:  #### 0 なら alimentt() を終了する
 35:        return
 36:
 37:    for YY in open(path+"ns8_keggID_sample_protein_ID.txt","r"):
```

**続行するパターンの変更箇所**

```
 32:    print(acid)
 33:    acid_p=len(acid) #### 先に acid_p(acidの要素数)を取得しておく
 34:
 35:    for YY in open(path+"ns8_keggID_sample_protein_ID.txt","r"):
 36:        YY1=re.sub("\n","",YY)
 37:        YY2=YY1.split("\t")
 38:        Y_moto=YY2[0]
 39:        #print(Y_moto)
 40:        Y_name=YY2[1]
 41:        Y = YY2[2]
 42:        if Y_moto==X_name:
 43:            print(Y_name)
 44:
 45:            #### acid_p が 0 なら以下の本来の処理は無駄らしいので
 46:            #### score1に名前とデータ数'0'(あるいは空文字)を詰めて追加して次のループへ
 47:            if acid_p == 0:
 48:                score1.append([Y_name, '0']) #### あるいは空文字列にする
 49:                continue    #### ここまで追加
 50:
 51:            N = len(X)
 52:            M = len(Y)
```